# Column with hash value is now a string after aliasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psql

I have a psql table with a column named `params` that contains a hash. Below is my scenario:

---

When I do the following query...

```
game = Game.select('games.params').where(id: 123).first
```

... it prints out...

```
p game.params.class # => !ruby/class 'ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Now I can go ahead an access values inside the returned hash normally.

---

**But when I give the column name an alias in my query (here is my problem)...**

```
game = Game.select('games.params as parameters').where(id: 123).first
```

... it prints out...

```
p game.parameters.class # => !ruby/class 'String'
```

---

I need to be able to change the column name in my query and then access the values inside the hash, but when I try to do `p game[:time]` it's being treated as a string.

I'm new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails, so this might be very simple to figure out but I am at a dead end right now.

Comment: Share your models that you are trying to join. Also, what is the data that you are trying to retrieve, share the exact query?

Answer (score 0):

What about this query:

```
g = Game.find 123
g.params
```

Comment: No, I need to be able to change the column name to anything other than `params` by using `where('params as somename')`

Comment: I do not know if I understand you, you want to change column name in your DB or in Rails model representation? You want to access params by eg. `game.parameters` ?

Comment: The latter. My exact scenario is, I am joining two tables that each have a column with the same name, so I need to change the column name in my query (alias). But when I do this, the hash gets turned into a string.